# Alert a moderator when an answer is improved after a post notice

Tags: feature-request, post-notices

I have been using some post notices lately, especially with new users that are not aware of some standards like writing a longer answer with some explanation rather than a single line.

A user has helped me letting me know that some of these users did improve their answers, so that I could remove the notice.

I'd like this to happen automatically. I mean, the system could warn me when there is a change in order to make things happen faster. This way, I could remove the post notice as soon as it's possible without manually checking all of the answers that I added the notice to. Of course, even if the system tells me it's back to a good quality standard, I'd still check the answer. I just think that it would come in handy to have a virtual help.

I'm not sure how we could do this, but a way could be to use the answer score? Since a low answer score triggers an automatic flag for low-quality content, why not use the same thing for this feature? If the score rises, the system would send me a notification saying that the answer has been improved since the post notice. I don't know if there would be a better way to do this, the developers will know better than me on this.

Comment: I'd rather base it on a substantial edit myself. Part of the reason I leave those notes is to discourage "I agree with this so I'll upvote it!" style behavior, which can certainly still happen with a post notice around

Comment: Post notices are a result of *questions* that tend to attract, or are attracting one-liner answers.  They shouldn't need to be removed if the question didn't change.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's not necessarily true. Some new users really write a single line but other answers are fine. This means that better answers are indeed possible. In any case, my request wouldn't remove my "judgement" over questions as well. :D

Comment: So you're putting the post notice on answers?  I see.  I don't do that; I delete the answer and put the post notice on the question.

Comment: Yes I use it on answers. You think questions are always guilty when you see one-line answers?

Comment: Not if it's just someone posting a bad answer.  But some questions are characteristically bikeshed.  I don't bother with post notices for people who are just posting lazy answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can see all the posts with notices on your site.

The link is of the form:

`http://<site>/annotated-posts?tab=noticed`

So for Stack Overflow you want https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed

For Programmers you want https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed

Comment: I try to look through these every month or so and burn the ones that haven't improved and removed it from the ones that no longer need it

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'd like this to be automatic though; hence my `feature-request`. Until then I'll use your solution. :)

Comment: @Alenanno - it was presented as a workaround.